# Confusion entre 'ante-' et 'anti-'

Tags: étymologie, histoire, préfixes, euphonie

Pourquoi 'Antéchrist', 'antichambre' et 'antidater' ? Est-ce purement euphonique ?

On notera qu'en anglais, par exemple, on a (plus logiquement) 'Antichrist', 'anteroom' et 'antedate'.

Comment: Anté veut dire celui qui précède tandis que anti veut dire le contre ou l'inverse

Comment: Dans le cas de l'antichrist, cela designe la personne qui est contre le christ et l'antéchrist veut dire que cette personne selon la bible va précéder le retour du christ, les sens sont différents mais les 2 sont correctes

Comment: @E.Abdel Le cas d'_antéchrist_ est assez particulier, c'est uniquement une déformation du préfixe "*anti-*". Ça n'a rien à voir avec le préfixe signifiant "*avant*", bien que ça prête fortement à confusion.

Comment: @Teleporting Goat merci pour l'info

Answer (score 3):

La réponse de LPH est très complète. On peut peut-être la parachever par l'analyse fine des rares exceptions où *anti-* semble avoir été substitué à *ante-*.

1. **Antichambre** : cet emprunt à l'italien n'a pas été modifié par l'Académie. Un mot comme anticour, par exemple, est en revanche devenu avant-cour (Féraud, 1788).
2. **Antidate** et antidater : le mot signifiait d'abord "avec une autre date", la notion d'antériorité est venue par la suite (voir le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/antidate)).
3. **Anticiper** et anticipation : emprunt direct du latin *anticipatio*.
4. **Antique** et famille : emprunt direct du latin *antiquus*.

Je n'en ai pas trouvé d'autres. Il est à noter qu'en lisant le dictionnaire latin  *Gaffiot* (y c. les noms propres), on constate que *ante* et *anti* sont beaucoup plus mobiles sémantiquement qu'en français. Ce qui nous surprend semblait banal aux Romains.

On peut aussi noter que certaines formes ont fait disparaitre la lettre finale ; antarctique, antanaclase, antagonisme, antalgie, antan.
Par ailleurs, d'autres préfixes ont concurrencé ces deux-là : *pré-* ou *avant-* d'un côté, *contr-* de l'autre.

Answer (score 2):

En ce qui concerne « anti- » à la place de « anté- » il s'agit seulement d'une variante orthographique que l'on trouve depuis un temps assez reculé et très souvent ; le TLFi n'a pas d'explication mais fournit des constations dans trois des parties de son entrée pour « anté- » ;

> - antébrachial, adj. dep. BESCH. 1845, ds les dict. gén.; Lar. 19e, Nouv. Lar. ill., QUILLET 1965 donnent la var. antibrachial
> - B. Hist. L'introd. du préf. en fr. a été favorisé par l'existence d'un certain nombre d'empr. en anté- (ou parfois en anti-) : antécédent (1361), …
> - Rem. On trouve, en m. fr. qq. var. en anti-; a) Avec valeur temp. : les empr. au lat. anticiper, anticipation, les composés antidate, antidater; b) Avec valeur spatiale, outre l'empr. à l'ital. antichambre qui subsiste en fr. mod., on trouve en m. fr.¹ : antibust, anti-cuisine, anti-poste notés ds HUG., antichapelle, anticour, antisalle notés ds GDF. Compl.

¹<sub>m. fr. : 1340 à 1611</sub>

Sous l'entrée « anti- » du TLFi une remarque montre que l'inverse n'est pas vrai ;

> b) On ne saurait considérer qu'il y a une var. anté- du suff., le seul mot en anté- signifiant « qui est le contraire de » étant l'empr. « antéchrist ».

Le Wiktionaire explique que « anti- » est un [préfixe synonyme](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/anti-#fr-pr%C3%A9f-2).

On doit donc considérer soit qu'il existe une variante orthographique, soit qu'il existe deux préfixes « anti- » l'un synonyme de « anté » et l'autre avec la signification habituelle de « opposé ».

Ce que l'on trouve à l'entrée pour « anti- » pourrait constituer le maillon qui mène à la réponse ;

> Le contenu de l'art. que Trév. 1732 consacre au morphème anti- est significatif : ,,Anti. Cette éspèce de préposition se trouve dans plusieurs mots François, en deux significations différentes car elle signifie quelquefois ce qui est avant, comme antichambre, ce qui est avant la chambre, et pour lors elle vient du Latin ante, avant;  quelquefois elle signifie ce qui est contraire, opposé, et pour lors elle vient du Grèc (anti) contrà, contre, comme antipode, …

Cela est vérifiable dans le [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/anti).

Je ne crois pas que l'euphonie ait un rapport avec cette déformation, laquelle semble être associée avec les emprunts au latin qui ont le préfixe latin « ante- » (transformé en « anti- »). Il n'existe pas d'explication raisonnablement accessible sur la toile. Il est possible que l'intention ait été de marquer cette famille d'emprunts de façon à identifier l'origine différente de celle des mots en « ante- » en tant que préfixe grec, mais cela se comprend  difficilement au vu de l'utilisation  contemporaine de « anti- » signifiant « contraire ».